# addSubview notification not received

Tags: memory, notifications, autorelease, ios4, addsubview

I'm facing a strange problem.. 
I want to add a UIViewcontroller (called iView) to my current View. 
I do it by calling

```
   iView = [[KFKaraokeInfosView alloc] initWithKaraoke:karaoke NibName:@"InfosView" commingFromPlayer:NO];
    iView.songTitle.text = karaoke.title;
    [self.view addSubview:iView.view];
```

In the viewDidLoad of iView, I add it as an observer to the NotificationCenter for a certain notification, like this

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.title = @"About";

        if ([karaoke.styles count] == 0)
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"GetInfosOfSong" object:self.karaoke];
        }
        else
        {
            shouldSetup = YES;
        }

        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setup) name:GetSongInfos  object:nil];
        [optionsTableView setBackgroundView:nil];

    }
```

The problem is when I call autorelease method  on iView at the initialisation, the notification is never catched (so setup method is never called), but if I don't call autorelease for iView, it works.

I don't understand the memory management in this situation, can someone help me to understand ?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do? Adding a child view in view controller containment? Or transitioning to the new view? Can you share the code that represents what you're doing with your controllers? When transitioning between view controllers, you should not be using `addSubview` and when doing view controller containment (i.e. making this new controller a portion of the screen represented by the current controllers), you should be doing `addChildViewController` and associated containment related calls. Bottom line, the answer depends upon what you're trying to do.

Comment: could you add your code where you add your notification as an observer

Comment: I'm triyng to add a child view in view controller containment, by displaying the new view like a popup, I just edited my question

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're doing the `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`, etc.?

Comment: are u in an ARC environment?

Comment: No i'm not in ARC environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container view controller methods are found in [Implementing a Container View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) of the *UIViewController Class Reference,* and sample code can be found in [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) of the *View Controller Programming Guide.*

Thus, in iOS 5 and later, you should probably have:

```
iView = [[[KFKaraokeInfosView alloc] initWithKaraoke:karaoke NibName:@"InfosView" commingFromPlayer:NO] autorelease];
[self addChildViewController:iView];
iView.songTitle.text = karaoke.title;
[self.view addSubview:iView.view];
[iView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

If this is iOS 4 or earlier, it doesn't support proper containment. You can manually kludge it, by adding the view like you are, with no `autorelease`:

```
iView = [[KFKaraokeInfosView alloc] initWithKaraoke:karaoke NibName:@"InfosView" commingFromPlayer:NO];
iView.songTitle.text = karaoke.title;
[self.view addSubview:iView.view];
```

You'd obviously keep a copy of the child view controller in some ivar of the parent view controller, not `autorelease` it, but rather explicitly `release` the child's controller when the child's view is dismissed. Note, since you're operating in a pre-containment iOS4 world, your child controller is not guaranteed of receiving various events (notoriously rotation events). But you should receive your notification center events.

---

An alternative to this ugliness of trying to fake containment in iOS 4 is to not use a child view controller at all, but just add the child view to the parent view. You can actually add it to the parent controller's NIB, but just hide it. Then, when you want to present it, unhide it. But keep everything in the parent view controller and it's NIB. The method that I described above, faking containment, might work (I've seen people do it), but it gives me the heebie jeebies. This is simpler.

Comment: I need to support IOS 4.3, is addChildViewController method supported by this version ?

Comment: Ah, no. Containment is not supported pre iOS 5. If you try to have controllers for subviews, it's going to get messy in iOS 4.

Comment: @Matthias Ah, no. Your problem is that if you `autorelease`, your controller is getting discarded on you, even though it's view is still on screen. So you'd really have to keep a copy of the child view controller in some ivar of the parent view controller, not `autorelease` it, but explicitly `release` the controller when the child view is dismissed. But since you're operating in a pre-containment iOS4 world, your child controller is not guaranteed of receiving various events (notoriously rotation events).

Comment: I understand.. I just thought that every time I added a subview to a view, i had to release it just after (like when i push a uiviewcontroller)

Comment: No, when you `pushViewController`, that's retaining it for you, so you can safely `autorelease` it. And when you do proper containment, `addChildViewController` also retains it for you. But in this case, you've got nothing to retain it for you, so you'll have to do that yourself, manually cleaning up after yourself and living with the fact that various view controller events will never get to your child controller. But you should receive your notification center events.

Comment: OK, so I'll do it that way ! Thanks a lot for you help @Rob!